# MariaDB error on installarion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mariadb

Whenever I try to install MariaDB I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
...
Fetched 12.1 MB in 3s (3,278 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: mysql-server: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 ajenti-v-mysql depends on mysql-server | mariadb-server; however:
  Package mysql-server is to be removed.
  Package mariadb-server is not installed.

(Reading database ... 99303 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Removing mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
mysql stop/waiting
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-10.0.
(Reading database ... 99227 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.21+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.21+maria-1~trusty) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.21+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb (--unpack)
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/mysql_system_tables.sql', which is also in package mysql-server-core-5.5 5.5.440ubuntu0.14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.21+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to find a solution to this problem, I usually find something related to *libmysqlclient18* but I don't think it has anything to do with this problem. At least the solutions don't work here.

Currently the server is on a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 and Ajenti control panel (nginx, php-fpm, mysql 5.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.21+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

These fixed it.